# I want to save .mp3 file in Android internal storage

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have Audio Clip in Unity's assets file. I would like to save this on Android's internal storage.
How can I save the contents of an assets file?
Is it impossible to convert from AudioClip to mp3?
If possible please tell me how to convert and save. Please.

Answer (score 0):

You should try researching your question like at least a little bit before asking it. I mean one google search and I found this [AudioClipToMp3](https://github.com/BeatUpir/Unity3D-save-audioClip-to-MP3). If you're wondering, that's the reason why everyone down voted your question.